# How to fetch notifications from Facebook

Tags: c#, .net, facebook

How to fetch notifications from face book. Is there any web-service or REST-based service by which we could fetch the notifications, contacts etc (like that in case of twitter).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's REST based, but it doesn't allow for simple HTTP logins like Twitter does.

The call you will want to use is: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Notifications.getList

You can read about authentication (using FB connect, requires an app-integrated browser instance) here: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Authorization_and_Authentication_for_Desktop_Applications or here (works with any browser): http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Auth.createToken

Since you seem to be using C#, you may want to look into this to get started: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/C_Sharp

Answer (score 0):

There's an RSS feed for the notifications.

Go to http://www.facebook.com/notifications and then at the top there's a little link called RSS. If you click on that, it opens the XML file for the notifications RSS feed.

Comment: harriyott, could you please be more precise.